# AJAX call using JSON data type returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, undefined

I have a jQuery function who sends an AJAX call to a PHP file to check selected value of a dropdown menu and using this value return data from DB.

```
jQuery (document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").change(function() {
        country = $("#country").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#address").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.code);
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Not working either with :

```
alert(data[0].code)
```

PHP Code:

```php
$country = $_POST["country"];
$stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM country WHERE name = :country");
$stmt -> execute(array(":country" => $country));
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $code = $row["code"];
}

echo json_encode($code);
```

Not working either with :

```
echo json_encode(array(":code" => $code));
```

The PHP script works fine as it return true value. Also when I check the Mozilla console the AJAX call sends the request to the PHP script correctly and it gets a return value too, but I still get `undefined` using alert.

Comment: You need to used `parseJSON` Like `var obj = $.parseJSON( data ); alert(obj.code)`.

Comment: I made your solution a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change This

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $code = $row["code"];
}
```

To

```
$code = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $code[] = $row["code"];
}
echo json_encode($code);
```

Comment: `console.log(data); ` and tell me what it is returning... @Lynxis

Comment: Return : Array [ "0" ] ! @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: how it could be an array ??

Comment: try `echo json_encode($rows);die;`  and check `console.log(data);`

Comment: Well I have no idea ! the code is exactly what u see in my question and the return is exactly what I posted here ! @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: Return : Array [ Object ] ! @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: When I try without : $code = array(); and $code = $row["code"]; it return : Object { :code: "0" } ! But still undefined when alerting !  @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: Thanks for ur answers, it helped me to find the problem :) @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: Well I can't accept ur answer because it's not the solution of my problem ! But maybe u can update ur answer ! @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: which method you have use now `echo json_encode($code);` or `echo json_encode (array ("code" => $code));`

Answer (score 0):

Must be something like this:

```
$country = $_POST["country"];
$stmt = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM country WHERE name = :country");
$stmt -> execute (array (":country" => $country));
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$code = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $code[] = $row["code"];
}
echo json_encode ($code);
```

or simply `echo json_encode ($rows);` as you use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

**The problem resolved with:**

```
echo json_encode (array ("code" => $code));
```

**I had a mistake using ":" before "code":**

```
echo json_encode (array (":code" => $code));
```